# iPhone builtin speaker partly not working

Tags: iphone, speakers

I have an iPhone 6 that is running iOS 8.3
Last night I got in the rain and my phone got a little wet too. Later I noticed that when I try to speak on the phone I cannot hear a single thing, also if I try to play music or use siri I cannot hear anything, but if alarm sets off or a timer or I have an incoming call the sound is working.

I tried restarting my phone but the situation remains. Not sure what is up with my phone and don't really want to pay for speaker replacement. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

I have also noticed that when I try to increase/decrease volume it says Headphones, however the phone is not connected to any headphones neither wired not wireless

Comment: Try inserting a headphone jack in to the headphone port a couple of times (but don't be too rough!) I had this problem with an old HTC where there was some debris causing a short in the port making the phone think it had headphones in. If that doesn't work, a cotton bud soaked in alcohol (as in, 100%) can help clean it, but make sure you switch the phone off!

Comment: I tried inserting earlier and it didn't help. I really don't think that it's the headphone jack as I haven't used headphones with the phone in the last couple of days. Usually it's connected via Bluetooth to my car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked it out. The entire time Bluetooth was on. Usually when I turn off my car the phone automatically disconnects. I guess this time something went wrong. Even after restarting the phone away from the off car the phone still thought it was connected. All it took is to turn Bluetooth off